# How to login with headless raspberry pi with Ubuntu 22.04.2 preinstalled?

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi

I have installed `ubuntu-22.04.2-preinstalled-desktop-arm64+raspi.img` on my Raspberry Pi 4. I was trying to login with default credentials but looks like it is disabled.

I was trying to SSH the RasPi but not sure what is the default user and steps to SSH.

Can any one guide me on the same?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1457486/edit) to offer plenty of details explaining "*I was trying to login with default credentials but looks like it is disabled*."

Comment: firstly the output when "*you try to login but looks like it is disabled*" is important that could help us to solve this problem. Secondly, there are lots of tutorials of using ssh to get remote connection to raspi, you should try it yourself  first,